# ASP.NET MVC How To

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

We have recently decided to switch from asp.net webforms to asp.net mvc for some new projects. As a long time webforms developer I have watched and read quite a lot of introductory tutorials and how to switch articles and video's. However some things still bug me (no pun intended) a litte bit. And I'm hoping I could get some answers from the community here.

First, we have a cms-system that we are required to use for a client. In the system they obviously manage the navigation (menu) for the webproject. My first question is, how would I go about to adding this dynamic navigation to all the pages (views). In webforms I would simply create a custom user control and throw it onto the masterpage or template. I suspect the answer to be viewmodels? Or partial views?

The second question is related. Often we would have a few pages that show some news for example in a side panel. Others would not. Would I create a different viewmodel for the different scenarios, work with sections?

I don't expect a definite answer, but more some guidelines/best practices. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Simply observer the open source CMS built on asp.net MVC. both of your  question 's answer you can get it form there. .

Comment: This question is *way* too broad to be answerable here in this format.

Comment: I do realise it is quite broad. I'm only looking for some sort of push in the right direction to continue the learning process. All comments are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad so I'll only give a high level way of achieving this.

For the menu system you can create two `Div` elements, one for the menu and one for the content.  The menu div should contain an `Action` that calls JavaScript to replace the content of the main `Div` with a `Partial View` returned by your `Controller`.

In your `_Layout` page you can something like this

```
<body>
     @Html.Action("RetrieveSideBar", "SideBar", new { area = "" })

     <div id="mainScreenDiv">                            
          @RenderBody()
     </div>
</body>
```

`RetrieveSideBar` renders the menu items

```
public class SideBarController : MyControllerBase {
   /// <summary>
   /// Retrieves the side bar.
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public ActionResult RetrieveSideBar() {
       var menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

       return PartialView("_SideBar", MenuItems());
   }

   private List<MenuItem> NotAuthenticatedMenuItems() {
       var menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
       menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "Register Firm", ActionUrl = Url.Action("Create", "FirmPreRegistration") });

       return menuItems;
   }
}
```

Where `MenuItem` is

```
public class MenuItem {
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string ActionUrl { get; set; }
}
```

`_SideBar` renders the menu as follows

```
@model List<MenuItem>

<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    @foreach (var menuItem in Model) {
        <li class="text-info leftMenuHeading ">
            <a href="#" onclick="NavigateTo('@menuItem.ActionUrl')">
            <span>@menuItem.Title</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Note that clicking on a `menu item` calls `NavigateTo` which is defined as follows in the '_Layout' page

```
function NavigateTo(view) {
   $.ajax({
        url: view,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
   success: function(data) {
       $('#mainScreenDiv').html(data);

   });
}
```

This creates an Ajax based navigation system that will replace the content in the page with the navigated page, note that `Action` methods need to return `PartialView` or else `_Layout` renders again.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer as it gave me some pointers as to what to do/explore next. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`My first question is, how would I go about to adding this dynamic navigation to all the pages (views). In webforms I would simply create a custom user control and throw it onto the masterpage or template.`

Asp.Net MVC has something similar - `_Layout.cshtml`. By default it is inside Views/Shared folder and it is like master page for all pages. You can generate your dynamic menu in following way

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public YourMenuModel YourMenuModel { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        this.YourMenuModel = //load dynamically your menu. For example from database

        ViewBag.MenuModel = this.YourMenuModel ;
    }
}
```

Inside _layout view you can get your menu model and render in any way

```
@{
var YourMenuModel = (YourMenuModel)ViewBag.MenuModel;
}
```

`Often we would have a few pages that show some news for example in a side panel. Others would not. Would I create a different viewmodel for the different scenarios, work with sections?`  
 
I would create partial view for news and put it inside some views

```
@Html.Partial("_YourNewsPartial")
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the partial views. I knew they existed, but I'll look into them in more depth